# Label dataChange event not getting fired

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

```
<mx:Label id="myLabel" dataChange="{trace('changed!!');}"  />
```

I change the text in the above label:

```
myLabel.text = "new text";
```

But nothing is traced as it's supposed to.

Am I using a wrong event? I thought **dataChange** is fired when text in the label is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event you want is `valueCommit`.  The `dataChange` event is specific to the `data` property, not `text`.

```
<mx:Label id="myLabel" text="1" valueCommit="trace('changed')" />
<mx:Button label="Click Me" click="myLabel.text += '1'" />
```